# how does this bash operation work in shell scipt

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ls

Hello i have come across a bash operation that i am finding hard to understand i have looked through the bash reference manual but have had no luck figuring out how this operation works.

i am having trouble understanding what the operation does i know ls -A will list all files including hidden files and the variable already has information stored within it, so what does the $() operation do.

this is the operation.

```
if [ "$(ls -A $variable)" ]
```

thanks for the feedback

Comment: `man test`. "STRING equivalent to -n STRING"

Comment: If you want a better command: `[[ $(find . -mindepth 1 -printf g -quit) ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if [ "$(ls -A $variable)" ]` will be true if the command `ls -A $variable` returns any output - the `$()` "operator" (or [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)) executes the command and returns it's output.

Answer (score 1):

1) See the manpage of `ls` :

> ```
> -A, --almost-all
>     do not list implied . and ..
> ```

2) The `$()` is an equivalent of backquotes (``) also called "command substitution". This corresponds to a sub-process execution.
In other words, the output of your command is catched by parentheses and could be affected to a variable like this :

```
var=$(ls -A)
echo "$var" # will print the output of ls -A
```

3) `[ "string" ]` or `[[ "string" ]]` or `test string` is equivalent of using -n option :

```
$ [[ "" ]] && echo "yes"
$ [[ "something" ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ -n "something" ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

See `man test` :

> ```
> -n STRING
>     the length of STRING is nonzero
> ```

So your command allows to check if the content of the current directory is not empty.